# Prevent *buntu from updating dictionaries during install

Tags: bash, xorg, dictionary, vagrant

In utilizing Vagrant to install an Ubuntu server box with a GUI (lxde), the shell provisioning fails due to what seems to be a frequent issue when setting up dictionaries.

The resolutions seem to all point to running scripts after the error has occurred, but this defeats the smooth automation script I'm after.

Is there anyway to prevent this step from taking place (all my apt-get installs are run with `-q -y`, in case that is related).

Is this related to X11 or to a specific desktop? I would not mind changing DE's to get around this...

**Vagrant log:**

```
==> development_environment: Setting up dictionaries-common (1.12.1ubuntu2) ...
==> development_environment: update-default-wordlist: Question empty but elements installed for class "wordlist"
==> development_environment:   dictionaries-common/default-wordlist: return code: "0", value: ""
==> development_environment:   Choices: , Manual symlink setting
==> development_environment:   shared/packages-wordlist: return code: "10" owners/error: "shared/packages-wordlist doesn't exist"
==> development_environment:   Installed elements: english (Webster's Second International English wordlist)
==> development_environment: 
==> development_environment:   Please see "/usr/share/doc/dictionaries-common/README.problems", section
==> development_environment:   "Debconf database corruption" for recovery info.
==> development_environment: update-default-wordlist: Selected wordlist "" 
==> development_environment: does not correspond to any installed package in the system
==> development_environment: and no alternative wordlist could be selected.
==> development_environment: dpkg: error processing dictionaries-common (--configure):
==> development_environment:  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
==> development_environment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of miscfiles:
==> development_environment:  miscfiles depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.20); however:
==> development_environment:   Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
==> development_environment: dpkg: error processing miscfiles (--configure):
==> development_environment:  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
==> development_environment: No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
==> development_environment: Errors were encountered while processing:
==> development_environment:  dictionaries-common
==> development_environment:  miscfiles
==> development_environment: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
==> development_environment: 
==> development_environment: (lxsession:1514): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell && /tmp/vagrant-shell

Stdout from the command:

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libfs6 libglu1-mesa x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-xfs-utils xfonts-scalable
  xinit xinput xorg-docs-core
Suggested packages:
  mesa-utils xorg-docs xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfs6 libglu1-mesa x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-xfs-utils xfonts-scalable
  xinit xinput xorg xorg-docs-core
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,448 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,064 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Abort.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
lxde is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up dictionaries-common (1.12.1ubuntu2) ...


Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
update-default-wordlist: Question empty but elements installed for class "wordlist"
  dictionaries-common/default-wordlist: return code: "0", value: ""
  Choices: , Manual symlink setting
  shared/packages-wordlist: return code: "10" owners/error: "shared/packages-wordlist doesn't exist"
  Installed elements: english (Webster's Second International English wordlist)

  Please see "/usr/share/doc/dictionaries-common/README.problems", section
  "Debconf database corruption" for recovery info.

update-default-wordlist: Selected wordlist "" 
does not correspond to any installed package in the system
and no alternative wordlist could be selected.
dpkg: error processing dictionaries-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of miscfiles:
 miscfiles depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.20); however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing miscfiles (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dictionaries-common
 miscfiles
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: OP left the question by migrating to fluxbox

Answer (score 0):

Without any answers to this, I had simply switched to using Fluxbox, which allowed the script to continue unimpeded through to GUI booting and subsequent install scripts.